# How do I achieve an animated gif in MS Access while queries are running?

Tags: vba, gif, ms-access-2013

This  the method I tried and it does not work:

1. I have a LoadingPopup form that pops up right before the queries start
2. The form contains a gif in an ActiveX control
3. The form is closed after the queries are done running

What actually happens is the LoadingPopup appears and then freezes while the queries are running, so there is no animation!

I am at a loss of what to do. What is the next best option for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hosed. Access is single-threaded, so while it is busy doing something (running a query) it won't do something else (animating a GIF).

Display a static picture. The users don't care anyway.

Comment: The users **shouldn't** care, but they are a sucker for "pretty visuals". But thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but, I'm working around on this with two databases. One does the major work and another is responsible for JUST showing a form with a loading image, percentage of progress and current action.

The 2nd form is binded into a table, refreshed using the OnTimer event (I also use OnTimer to animate my picturebox).

This table should be linked with my primary database, and it is updated with the query progress data.

You can use some code for hiding the 2nd Access (just displaying the form).

This way I can give a much better user experience.

Best,